# Creating a DRY version of gatsby-browser.js gatsby-ssr.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

In my build I have two files with the same code: `gatsby-browser.js` and `gatsby-ssr.js`. The code is pretty simple, it uses `wrapPageElement` to wrap pages in a `<Layout />` component:

```js
// gatsby-browser.js  gatsby-ssr.js

import React from 'react';
import Layout from './src/components/Layout';

export function wrapPageElement({ element, props }) {
  return <Layout {...props}>{element}</Layout>;
}
```

I'd like to hand this code off to one file and then import it into both documents, thereby giving it the DRY treatment, but I'm a bit unsure on the best way of doing this. Can anyone suggest a best practice here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file named whatever you want (`wrapPageElement.js` for example, original) with the following content:

```
const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => {
   return <Layout {...props}>{element}</Layout>;
}
export default wrapPageElement
```

Now, both in your `gatsby-ssr.js` and `gatsby-browser.js`:

```
import customWrapPageElement from './wrapPageElement' 

export const wrapPageElement = customWrapPageElement
```

Keep in mind that you will be able to use DRY until certain point, since both files have the same content but it's intended to be like this because both instances have a different effect in Gatsby's environment.

Comment: You can also do `export { default as wrapPageElement } from "./wrapPageElement"` for a more succinct approach when appropriate.

Comment: Yeah good point about the two files likely needing to diverge. Still, I learnt something today and chances are I won't need to change either of these files with this :-) thanks!